How to read GDB's backtrace?
I am trying to understand GDB better. One question I wanted to start with is how to read a backtrace generated by GDB.
An example of a backtrace I am working on:
(gdb) bt
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>)
    at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>)
    at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6)
    at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007c4104c4526e in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#4  0x00007c4104c288ff in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x00007c4104c297b6 in __libc_message_impl (
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7c4104dce765 "*** %s ***: terminated\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:132
#6  0x00007c4104d36c19 in __GI___fortify_fail (
    msg=msg@entry=0x7c4104dce77d "stack smashing detected")
    at ./debug/fortify_fail.c:24
#7  0x00007c4104d37ea4 in __stack_chk_fail () at ./debug/stack_chk_fail.c:24
#8  0x000062ba08db41be in main (argc=2, argv=0x7ffea53e6408) at stack.c:15

What does the first address listed in each entry mean? I assumed it was the location of the function that the entry mentions, like the address of main is 0x000062ba08db41be. I was able to use the disassemble option in GDB and this seems to confirm my assumption. However, when I try to disassemble #7's entry, like "disassemble 0x00007c4104d37ea4", I get the following output "No function contains specified address."
Please explain?
